# How to use MediaCodec without MediaExtractor for H264

Tags: android, h.264, stagefright, android-mediacodec, transport-stream

I need to use MediaCodec without the MediaExtractor and I'm reading the file using a FileInputStream. Currently it is not working, it is showing a greenish scrambled image on the screen.

This is the whole source code:

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("/sdcard/sample.ts");

String mimeType = "video/avc";
MediaCodec decoder = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(mimeType);
MediaFormat format = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(mimeType, 1920, 1080);

byte[] header_sps = { 0, 0, 0, 1, 103, 100, 0, 40, -84, 52, -59, 1, -32, 17, 31, 120, 11, 80, 16, 16, 31, 0, 0, 3, 3, -23, 0, 0, -22, 96, -108 };
byte[] header_pps = { 0, 0, 0, 1, 104, -18, 60, -128 };
format.setByteBuffer("csd-0", ByteBuffer.wrap(header_sps));
format.setByteBuffer("csd-1", ByteBuffer.wrap(header_pps));
format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_MAX_INPUT_SIZE, 1920 * 1080);
format.setInteger("durationUs", 63446722);

decoder.configure(format, surface, null, 0);
decoder.start();

ByteBuffer[] inputBuffers = decoder.getInputBuffers();
ByteBuffer[] outputBuffers = decoder.getOutputBuffers();
BufferInfo info = new BufferInfo();
boolean isEOS = false;
long startMs = System.currentTimeMillis();

while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
    if (!isEOS) {
        int inIndex = decoder.dequeueInputBuffer(1000);
        if (inIndex >= 0) {
            byte buffer2[] = new byte[18800 * 8 * 8 * 8];
            ByteBuffer buffer = inputBuffers[inIndex];
            int sampleSize;

            sampleSize = in.read(buffer2, 0, 18800 * 4);

            buffer.clear();
            buffer.put(buffer2, 0, sampleSize);
            buffer.clear();

            if (sampleSize < 0) {
                decoder.queueInputBuffer(inIndex, 0, 0, 0, MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM);
                isEOS = true;
            } else {
                decoder.queueInputBuffer(inIndex, 0, sampleSize, 0, 0);
            }
        }
    }

    int outIndex = decoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, 10000);
    switch (outIndex) {
    case MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED:
        Log.d("DecodeActivity", "INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED");
        outputBuffers = decoder.getOutputBuffers();
        break;
    case MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED:
        Log.d("DecodeActivity", "New format " + decoder.getOutputFormat());
        break;
    case MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER:
        Log.d("DecodeActivity", "dequeueOutputBuffer timed out! " + info);
        break;
    default:
        ByteBuffer buffer = outputBuffers[outIndex];
        Log.v("DecodeActivity", "We can't use this buffer but render it due to the API limit, " + buffer);

        while (info.presentationTimeUs / 1000 > System.currentTimeMillis() - startMs) {
            try {
                sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                break;
            }
        }
        decoder.releaseOutputBuffer(outIndex, true);
        break;
    }

    if ((info.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) != 0) {
        Log.d("DecodeActivity", "OutputBuffer BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM");
        break;
    }
}

decoder.stop();
decoder.release();
```

If I use the MediaExtractor, everything works fine. I got the SPS/PPS values by looking at the MediaFormat when using MediaExtractor. If I remove the section below, nothing is shown on the screen.

```
byte[] header_sps = { 0, 0, 0, 1, 103, 100, 0, 40, -84, 52, -59, 1, -32, 17, 31, 120, 11, 80, 16, 16, 31, 0, 0, 3, 3, -23, 0, 0, -22, 96, -108 };
byte[] header_pps = { 0, 0, 0, 1, 104, -18, 60, -128 };
format.setByteBuffer("csd-0", ByteBuffer.wrap(header_sps));
format.setByteBuffer("csd-1", ByteBuffer.wrap(header_pps));
format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_MAX_INPUT_SIZE, 1920 * 1080);
format.setInteger("durationUs", 63446722);
```

What I am missing? How can I get the SPS/PPS values programatically without MediaExtractor?

Comment: could you share with us the corrected code please??

Comment: Are SPS and PPS values you used standard values? In my case, I am getting the data in the form of NAL units, so i am searching for frames with NAL type 7 and 8 for PPS and SPS. Instead can I use the above values directly? Also, I did not understand the posted answer clearly. Can you explain what exactly was the problem with your code? I am using this code as a reference for my scenario.

Comment: No, each stream has its own SPS/PPS values, you should get them like you mentioned above. The problem was that I was sending to MediaCodec (queueInputBuffer) a fixed-size buffer (with size 18800 * 4), but instead you should send complete video frames only. Is it clear now?

Comment: There is a way to exclude `MediaExtractor` and put `byte[]` frame (one by one) directly to the inputBuffer (`ByteBuffer`). Is this what you actually want?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm assuming you're reading a raw H.264 elementary stream and not an MP4 file.

It looks like you're feeding fixed-size blocks of data to the decoder.  That doesn't work.  You need to put a single access unit into each buffer.

Comment: That was the problem! Now I'm feeding the decoder only with video packets and it is working!

Comment: @thiagolr Can you post the solution? How you solved this.. I am stuck at

`decoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, 10000);`

I always get -1...

Answer (score 7):

To your last question i.e. **how can you get `SPS` and `PPS` values**, you need to have a mechanism to read the same from the file.

If you are having an `elementary stream` file, then you would need to parse the file, identify `NALU` headers and extract the content.

If you have `container` format, you will need to have a mechanism to read the `file format` of the `container` type and extract the information.

If you have a `streaming` input, then you can receive the content from the incoming `SDP` information.

As for your current code, I would recommend concatenating both `SPS` and `PPS` into one buffer and provide the same to the underlying `codec` as shown below

```
byte[] csd_info = { 0, 0, 0, 1, 103, 100, 0, 40, -84, 52, -59, 1, -32, 17, 31, 120, 11, 80, 16, 16, 31, 0, 0, 3, 3, -23, 0, 0, -22, 96, -108, 0, 0, 0, 1, 104, -18, 60, -128 };
format.setByteBuffer("csd-0", ByteBuffer.wrap(csd_info));
format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_MAX_INPUT_SIZE, 1920 * 1080);
format.setInteger("durationUs", 63446722);
```

Comment: The main issue was fixed with the other (accepted) answer. But thanks for answering the second question! +1 for that!

Comment: MediaCodec codecs appear to differ among devices about what constitutes a NAL unit. Some want the 0001 pattern at the beginning, others not. Others are fussy about what you do with non-VCL units.

Comment: @PaulSteckler.. It's the implementation of the decoders which is making a difference. Some codecs stick to `RTP` standard and don't handle a start code. An example of this is `H.264` streaming to `Quicktime` which doesn't display the video if a start code is present as `RTP` standard mandates that first byte is the `NALU`type. Ideally, a decoder should be capable of searching for a start code and be robust enough to handle variations.