# Android MediaCodec not working

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

I'm trying to directly decode the H.264 encoded camera output of the Raspberry Pi camera module on an android device, but my code fails to properly decode the file. I get no output, and as the last frame I get a garbled image.

As I am parsing the input file myself (it is an H.264 byte-stream) into NAL units, I'm left with a question: when feeding them to the MediaCodec buffers, do I feed the NAL unit separator into the buffer as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MediaCodec` decoder requires an H.264 elementary stream, and wants one access unit per buffer.  You also need to supply SPS/PPS before the first data packet (either through the `BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG` flag or by adding it to the `MediaFormat`).

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19742047/how-to-use-mediacodec-without-mediaextractor-for-h264).

Comment: I understand that, it is exactly how I'm feeding the buffer. However, while parsing it is unclear whether or not I should include the start code prefix in the buffer or strip that away during parsing.

Comment: As an aside: I'm now sending SPS and PPS in two separate buffers. Should they be combined into one buffer?