# Why am I getting "Unsupported format" errors, reading H.264 encoded rtsp streams with the Android MediaPlayer?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, h.264, stagefright

I am trying to show H.264 encoded rtsp video on an Android device. The stream is coming from a Raspberry Pi, using vlc to encode `/dev/video1` which is a "Pi NoIR Camera Board".

```
vlc-wrapper -vvv v4l2:///dev/video1 --v4l2-width $WIDTH --v4l2-height $HEIGHT --v4l2-fps ${FPS}.0 --v4l2-chroma h264 --no-audio --no-osd --sout "#rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8000/pi.sdp}" :demux=h264 > /tmp/vlc-wrapper.log 2>&1
```

I am using very minimal Android code right now:

```
final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);
try {
  mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
  mediaPlayer.prepare();
```

and getting a "Prepare failed.: status=0x1" `IOException`. When I look at the logs, I see lines like

```
06-02 16:28:05.566 W/APacketSource(  316): Format:video 0 RTP/AVP 96  / MIME-Type:H264/90000
06-02 16:28:05.566 W/MyHandler(  316): Unsupported format. Ignoring track #1.
06-02 16:28:05.566 I/MyHandler(  316): SETUP(1) completed with result -1010 (Unknown error 1010)
```

coming from a system process. Grepping for these messages points to the  `libstagefright/rtsp` sources, and *seems to* mean that the `ASessionDescription::getDimensions` call in the `APacketSource::APacketSource` constructor is failing. This doesn't seem like it should be happening, because VLC certainly knows what dimensions to output:

```
[0x1c993a8] v4l2 demux debug: trying specified size 800x600
[0x1c993a8] v4l2 demux debug: Driver requires at most 262144 bytes to store a complete image
[0x1c993a8] v4l2 demux debug: Interlacing setting: progressive
[0x1c993a8] v4l2 demux debug: added new video es h264 800x600
```

What *seems to* be happening is that `ASessionDescription::getDimensions` is looking for a `framesize` attribute in the (seemingly well-formed) `DESCRIBE` results

```
06-02 16:28:05.566 I/MyHandler(  316): DESCRIBE completed with result 0 (Success)
06-02 16:28:05.566 I/ASessionDescription(  316): v=0
06-02 16:28:05.566 I/ASessionDescription(  316): o=- 15508012299902503225 15508012299902503225 IN IP4 pimple
06-02 16:28:05.566 I/ASessionDescription(  316): s=Unnamed
06-02 16:28:05.566 I/ASessionDescription(  316): i=N/A
06-02 16:28:05.566 I/ASessionDescription(  316): c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
06-02 16:28:05.566 I/ASessionDescription(  316): t=0 0
06-02 16:28:05.566 I/ASessionDescription(  316): a=tool:vlc 2.0.3
06-02 16:28:05.566 I/ASessionDescription(  316): a=recvonly
06-02 16:28:05.566 I/ASessionDescription(  316): a=type:broadcast
06-02 16:28:05.566 I/ASessionDescription(  316): a=charset:UTF-8
06-02 16:28:05.566 I/ASessionDescription(  316): a=control:rtsp://192.168.1.35:8000/pi.sdp
06-02 16:28:05.566 I/ASessionDescription(  316): m=video 0 RTP/AVP 96
06-02 16:28:05.566 I/ASessionDescription(  316): b=RR:0
06-02 16:28:05.566 I/ASessionDescription(  316): a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
```

This *looks like* it may be a Stagefright bug: It knows (or should know) that it has a H.264  encoded stream, yet it seems to be expecting a H.263 `framesize` attribute. Hence my questions:

1. Am I reading the sources right? Is the problem in the `ASessionDescription::getDimensions` call? (Does stagefright only actually support H.263 streaming?)
2. Or is the Pi-side code wrong in some way?
3. Or am I just missing a key step or two in my client-side code?

#### Update, 20140606:

The `MediaPlayer` docs say that -1010 is [MEDIA_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#MEDIA_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED): "Bitstream is conforming to the related coding standard or file spec, but the media framework does not support the feature." This makes me wonder if the problem is the 'standard' progressive download issue. That is, [Supported Media Formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#recommendations) says

> For video content that is streamed over HTTP or RTSP [in a] MPEG-4 [container] the `moov` atom must precede any `mdat` atoms, but must succeed the `ftyp` atom

while most streams put the `moov` atom last.

I am not at all sure how to verify this, though!

- I see no `moov` or `ftyp` atoms in the vlc source. (I am *told* that vlc is just streaming, here; that the actual H264 content is coming out of the camera driver.)
- I see no `moov` or `ftyp` atoms in the https://github.com/raspberrypi linux or userland branches. (Maybe I'm just grepping for the wrong things, though.)
- When I have vlc save the stream, I get an mp4 file with `moov` before `mdat`, but of course vlc could be doing some transcoding, here.

#### Update, 20140610:

The [GPAC "Osmo4" player](http://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/downloads/gpac-nightly-builds/#Android) can display the stream on an Android 4.3 tablet. Badly (more lag than VLC on a laptop, and prone to lockups) but it **can** display it.

#### Update, 20140616:

When I tried grepping the VLC sources again (case-insensitive and without word-orientation, this time) I did find the FOURCC macros defining the `moov` and `ftyp` atoms in `modules/mux/mp4.c`, which quickly led to the `--sout-mp4-faststart` (and `--no-sout-mp4-faststart`) switches ... which don't make any difference.

So, it looks like it may actually not be an atom-ordering issue. That's good to know, if it closes off a whole class of dead-ends, but it does leave me banging my head against the wall (which always seem to do more damage to my head than to the wall) without a clue.

#### Update, 20140702:

I compiled VLC for Android, and it can display the stream generated by VLC on the pi. It puts the image in the top-left of the screen; I tried writing my own skin for their .so, and couldn't find any 'knobs' that would let me zoom-to-surface or whatever. (Plus the .apk came to about 12M!)

So, I found the relevant RFCs and wrote my own RTSP client. Or tried to: I can parse the [SDP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2327) and generate enough valid [RTSP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2326) to get [RTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3550) and RTCP datagrams, and I can parse the RTP and RTCP headers. But even though the SDP claims to deliver m=video 0 RTP/[AVP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3551) 96 and a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000, the `MediaCodec` won't display video on my surface, no matter which of the three H264 codecs on my tablet I pass to [MediaCodec.createByCodecName()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html#createByCodecName(java.lang.String)), and when I look at the RTP payloads, I'm not too surprised: I don't see the [NAL sync pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13307086/decoding-raw-h264-stream-in-android?rq=1) anywhere in any of the packets.

Instead, they *all* start with either `21 9A __ 22 FF` (usually) or occasionally `3C 81 9A __ 22 FF`, where the __ seems to always be an even number that goes up by 2 each packet. I don't recognize this pattern - do you?

#### Update, 20140711:

Turns out that H264 packets don't have to start with the NAL sync pattern - that's only necessary where NAL Units may be embedded in a larger data stream. My RTP packets are in [RFC 6184](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6184) format.

Comment: can you read the same stream with another app, e.g. VLC?

Comment: Huh - I'm surprised I didn't mention that. Yes, VLC can read the stream ... but, of course, VLC is willing to open a second stream to find the moov atom and Android is not. (Sorry, reference to that is on machine at work.)

Comment: http://bytechunk.net/mobile_progressive_playback/index.php

Comment: Actually, I thought you tried VLC playback on Android…

Comment: I have had success with encoding video for mobile playback using a combination of imagemagic (I use this to stitch images together) and avconv (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/avconv.1.html) Both run nicely on linux and as the RPi is linux based neither should be a problem for you to get working. Just a suggestion. Worth looking into as I have had little success with any other tools

Answer (score 5):

After an amazing amount of dead-ends, I can show a H264 RTSP stream on an Android `SurfaceView`. This answer is only *sort of* an answer because I still can't address my original three questions, but even full of bug and shortcuts as it is, my 75K apk is a lot better than Vlc for Android or the osmo4 player: It has sub-second latency (at least when the sender and the receiver are on the same wifi router!) and fills the `SurfaceView`.

A few takeaways, to help anyone trying to do anything similar:

- All input buffers you pass to [`MediaCodec.queueInputBuffer()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html#queueInputBuffer(int,%20int,%20int,%20long,%20int)vvvv) must start with the 00 00 01 [sync pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13307086/decoding-raw-h264-stream-in-android).
- You can [`configure()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html#configure(android.media.MediaFormat,%20android.view.Surface,%20android.media.MediaCrypto,%20int)) and [`start()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html#start()) the codec right away - but don't queue any 'normal' input buffers until you've see both an SPS (NALU code 7) and PPS (NALU code 8) packet. (These might not be 0x67 and 0x68 - the "nal_ref_idc" bits should be non-zero but will not necessarily be 11. Fwiw, `vlc` seems to always give me 01.)
- Pass the SPS/PPS packets *almost* normally - pass the [BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html#BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG) flag to `queueInputBuffer()`. In particular, don't try to put them in a "csd-0" buffer attached to the `MediaFormat`!
- When you see (a) missed frame(s) (*i.e.* you see a jump in RTP sequence number) **do not** call [`codec.flush()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html#flush())! Just skip the partial frame, and don't queue up a bufer until the next full frame.