# Is MediaCodec performance/latency affected by the frame resolution on Android?

Tags: android, h.264, rtsp, android-mediacodec

I am creating an application that receives an RTSP streaming that is H264 encoded and the application has to decode it using MediaCodec to be finally displayed. Something similar to the one mentioned in this [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24005714/why-am-i-getting-unsupported-format-errors-reading-h-264-encoded-rtsp-streams/26807357#26807357).

I wonder if some knows if mediaCodec performance will be affected by a change on resolution on the RTSP streaming, specifically the latency and ARM consumption.

I know MediaCodec is accelerated by Hardware so I would expect a pretty stable latency and ARM consumption but if someone has some numbers on performance it would be great to compare if my application could be doing something silly causing more load on the ARM.

I can't test this myself right now because I am trying to figure out the correct format for the buffers that media codec would expect for H264 once I get the RTSP payload.

Comment: You may find the working solution on [github](https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming). Regarding the performance implications of higher resolutions, there still are some byte array copies in user space, and also _after_ decoding.

Comment: Thanks @AlexCohn, I will check it, I thought that libstreaming was just for the RTSP server side (encode+streaming) and not for the client side (decode+display). I am going to review it