# Stream video from Unity to Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, rtsp

I'm looking for a way to stream the video of a Unity Camera, to an Android device, so as to show it on screen.

On Unity's side, I've found [a fork of FFMPEGOut](https://github.com/keijiro/FFmpegOut/pull/36) which can stream the camera view over UDP, either as raw or RTSP stream. It has about 2s of delay, but it's the only option that I have found.

From Android, I'd like to connect to this stream and somehow extract the frames to YUV frames. I then have an OpenGL Renderer to show these frames on screen.

However I am very confused with the options that I've found:

- FFMPEG seems pretty complicated to use in an Android app, I couldn't find a simple library without using NDK
- MediaCodec might also be an option ([see this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13307086/decoding-raw-h264-stream-in-android)), but I am also confused as to how to decode a stream of H264 frames to YUV

I am not even sure what protocol I should use to stream the data (probably over UDP?). Any help or documentation would be greatly appreciated.